# Open Auth Authentication in ASP .NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I am writing a ASP .NET WEB API Application which can be accessed by other devices and applications to interact with my Application hosted in IIS. How can I give OpenAuth Authentication for the WEB API Application. Am using MVC 4 in VS 2010 and hence my framework is 4.0. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate a web API using Individual Accounts. Protected recource will contains the Www-Authenticate header with value "Bearer", indicating that the client must authenticate using a bearer token.

A bearer token is a particular type of access token. An access token is a credential string that authorizes a client to access a protected resource. (See [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4).) A bearer token is an access token that can be used by any client. In other words, a client can use the token without proving that the token was issued to that particular client. (See [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).) For this reason, bearer tokens must be used with SSL. If you transmit a bearer token as plaintext, anyone can intercept it and get access to the protected resource.

All info about that can be found **[HERE](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)**